# Unmarshal from array of MongoDB subdocuments with mgo Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am trying to figure out how to get a single subdocument from an array and unmarshal it into a struct.

My mongo document looks like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc123"), 
    "gamecode" : "abc123"
    "players" : [ 
        { 
            "playerid" : ObjectId("abc123"), 
            "username" : "test", 
        },
        { 
            "playerid" : ObjectId("abc456"), 
            "username" : "test2"
        }]
 }
```

And I have a player struct that looks like this:

```
type Player struct {
    PlayerID bson.ObjectId `bson:"playerid" json:"playerid"`
    Username string        `bson:"username" json:"username"`
}
```

From the mongo command line I can do a

```
db.games.find(({"players.playerid": ObjectId('abc123')}, {"_id": 0, "players.$":1})
```

Which returns

```
{"players" : [{ "playerid" : ObjectId("abc123"), "username" : "test"}]}
```

But I am having a hard time figuring out how to implement this same functionality in Go so that I have a populated player struct from the result of the query. I have been playing around with different configurations of the code below, but it always results in an empty struct. What am I missing here?

```
player := Player{}
collection.Find(bson.M{"players.playerid": bson.ObjectIdHex(pid)}).Select(bson.M{"_id": 0, "players.$": 1}).One(&player)
```

I am running the latest MongoDB version and am using the mgo.v2 driver for Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't capture a single player, you capture players.
like in the response from the mongo command:

```
{"players" : [{ "playerid" : ObjectId("abc123"), "username" : "test"}]}
```

Sounds like you can you an abstraction for a `game`

```
type Game struct {
    Players []Player `bson:"players"`
}
```

And your call would be into `&game`

```
var game Game
collection.Find(bson.M{"...").One(&game)
```